# Using Mimes for Validating Laravel File Post - Word File

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, forms, http-post

I have a form that I post file. I am trying to use validation to accept only word documents. I tried using mime types however doesn't seem to work and I couldn't spot my mistake.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('myFile') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
           <div class="form-material">
               <input class="form-control" type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile">
               <label for="myFile">MyFile</label>
               @if ($errors->has('myFile'))
                    <div {{ $errors->first('myFile') }}</div>
               @endif
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

This posts successfully and I receive it in my controller.

In my controller, I try to validate it, however it is always returning the error, even though the file is in '.doc' format.

```
public function myController(Request $request) {
     $validator = MyValidations::myFormValidator($request->all());

     if ($validator->fails()) {
          $this->throwValidationException(
               $request, $validator
          );
     }

     ...
}
```

and the validator:

```
public static function myFormValidator($data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'myFile' => 'required|mimes:application/msword'

        // I also tried
        // 'myFile' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx'
    ]);
}
```

---

Edit: I have seen some posts on SO, regarding that there is a file `config > mimes.php` but I don't have it on Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is nothing really wrong with your validation code. The problem is that your form is not submitting the files properly.

Add the proper `enctype` to your form like so:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also make sure to get the syntax right for validation (but I think you knew this part). Use either of these two:

```
'myFile' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx'
'myFile' => 'required|mimetypes:application/msword'
```

Comment: Ohh.. Couldn't notice it in the beginning. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'myFile': 'required|mimes:doc,docx'
```

Comment: It's exactly what I tried and written on my last snippet. It doesn't work. I still receive 'The myFile must be a file of type doc, docx.'

Comment: I have other validations working with my syntax. Your syntax won't work as colon is not the right way inside dictionary. I need to use `=>` instead